# I can see that API is responding in console Network Panel but when i call it from POSTMAN it give 200 response with blank page

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, postman

I want to get data from this api url:-
https://epaper.livehindustan.com/Home/getstorydetail?Storyid=13059549
I get story id from another API but those are working properly.
But main issue is that it is giving response in the website when its called from ajax call in js side but when i call it from postman it give blank response with 200 status.
[Network response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZcQP.png)

As shown in the screenshot its is working properly in webpage.

[POSTMAN response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IACv.png)

JavaScript AJAX code is as follows:-

```
function ShowLinkedStory(storyid) {
    $("#divlinkedstory").empty();
    if (storyid <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    var isSubArticle = 0;
    var SmallImg = 0;
    var url = BaseUrl + "Home/getstorydetail";
    var param = { Storyid: storyid };
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "Get",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: param,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            result = data;
            //logic on result data
        },
        error: function (e) {
            result = "Error";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well then something about the request you are making in postman, must significantly differ from that your browser makes. But we can not possibly know what, based on what little information you have given us. Please go read [ask].

Comment: Maybe it needs a cookie with a session id or a token that exists when in the website context, but that you did not supply with your postman request. Maybe it just wants a User-Agent request header, that mimics that of a current browser. Or maybe it is one of a multitude of other things. If you are _supposed_ to be using this API, then there should be some documentation for it?

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your postman request as well

Comment: This really needs debugging on the server-side to see what it is doing when the request comes in.